# Increase Width of animated arch on Circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I <s>created</s> stole an animated circle with a timer. I need to change the width of the animated arch of the circle.

How can I do that as I can't figure it out.

This is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yEkWY/1/)

I am attaching the width of the animated arch with the following CSS:

**CSS:**

```css
.timer > #slice > .pie {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    width:160px; /* 170 - (2 * border width) */
    height:160px; /* 170 - (2 * border width) */
    clip:rect(0em,0.5em,1em,0em);
    -moz-border-radius:0.5em;
    -webkit-border-radius:0.5em; 
    border-radius:0.5em; 
}
```

**JS:**

```js
$('div.timer'+instance).html('<div class="percent"></div><div id="slice"'+(percent > 50?' class="gt50"':'')+'><div class="pie"></div>'+(percent > 50?'<div class="pie fill"></div>':'')+'</div>');
```

Comment: increase the border size to `10px` then reduce the width & height to `150px`. http://jsfiddle.net/yEkWY/4/

Comment: Also try to use RequestAnimationFrame for javascript animations, not interval since interval is really bad for performance and a ANTI pratice.
Source: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yEkWY/2/)

You can do this in `.timer > #slice > .pie{`

```css
.timer > #slice > .pie {
  border: 10px solid blue;
  position:absolute;
  width:150px; /* 170 - (2 * border width) */
  height:150px; /* 170 - (2 * border width) */
  clip:rect(0em,0.5em,1em,0em);
  -moz-border-radius:0.5em;
  -webkit-border-radius:0.5em; 
  border-radius:0.5em; 
}
```

I doubled the `border` size and then made the `width` and `height` 10px smaller.

Answer (score -2):

you have to do changes in  width attribute .

chnage Pixel level  then it will work for you

```
width:160px; /* 170 - (2 * border width) */
```

Ex:-`width:190px;`

Comment: Please test or show a JSFiddle before posting an awsner.
This would be your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yEkWY/7/